# Child Theme - Changing Header

Tags: customization

I'm pretty new to WordPress, so please forgive any ignorances.

I have a child theme which I've implemented, which works okay, but I need to display a banner in the header section, where there is no widget area. The idea is that I use a custom field to identify some aspect of the page, and then display a banner according to that value.

So, I found that I could copy `header-main.php` into `/my-child-theme/parts/`, and add some additional code which identifies the field value and then queries a non-WP database. This works okay too. No problems.

However, I realize that when the main theme gets updated my `header-main.php` file (in the child theme) will not get updated, which could later cause issues.

So, I'm wondering if there is a better way or, rather, a correct way of achieving what I'm attempting to do, taking account of the fact that I need the banner to be in a specific place in the header section.

Any suggestions/help appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understand what you're trying to achieve, but can you make a check on the value of your custom field? Something like this:

```
if( $field == 'banner' ) {
     // Display banner
}
```

You can put the code straight into your parent theme's `header-main.php` and it will only execute if the value of $field is equal to 'banner', like in the case of your child theme.

Comment: I think the question is quite clear. I certainly wouldn't want to put the code directly into the parent theme's `header-main.php`; that would be even worse than putting it in the child theme's `header-main.php`.